# Number of choices vs number of distinct permutations of duplicate elements

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I ran into an approach of encoding lattice paths with strings of $U$ and $R$ (to signify direction of $Up$ and $Down$ by a single unit) and it was mentioned for the case that we have a string of $6$ $U$ and $3$ $R$ how many strings are there?
The answer was that there are $9$ positions of which $3$ positions must be $U$ and once we know where the $U$ are the rest has to be $R$ and so the answer of the number of such strings mentioned was $9 \choose 3$

Now this type of string $UUUUUURRR$ reminded me of a formula of counting the number of *distinct* permutations of of duplicate items which is:
$\frac{n!}{p!q!r!...}$ where $p$ items are identical, $q$ items are identical, $r$ items are identical.

If I apply the same formula here we have $p = 6$ for $U$ since we have six identical elements and $q = 3$ for three identical $R$ so we have:
$\frac{9!}{6!3!}$ but this equals $9 \choose 3$

So are these formulas the same or are they have some relation?

Comment: The general formula you stated is for a multinomial coefficient.  If there are only two types of objects, you obtain a binomial coefficient.

Comment: The second formula you mentioned is the multinomial coefficient, which counts the number of unique permutations of several groups of indistinguishable objects. So the binomial coefficient is simply the special case, where there are two groups of objects.

Comment: @AndreasLenz: But there in the binomial coefficients or $n \choose r$ we also have $(n - r)!$ in the denumerator which we don't have in the other case

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: Same comment as above

Answer (score 2):

We wish to count the number of permutations of $n = n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + \cdots + n_k$ objects, with $n_i$ of type $i$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$. We can select $n_1$ of $n$ positions for objects of the first type, $n_2$ of the remaining $n - n_1$ positions for objects of the second type, $n_3$ of the remaining $n - n_1 - n_2$ for objects of the third type, and so forth until we select $n_k$ of the remaining $n - n_1 - n_2 - n_3 - \cdots - n_{k - 1}$ positions for objects of the $k$th type.  Hence, the number of ways we can permute $n = n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + \cdots + n_k$ objects, with $n_i$ objects of type $i$, $1 \leq i \leq k$, is
\begin{align*}
& \binom{n}{n_1}\binom{n - n_1}{n_2}\binom{n - n_1 - n_2}{n_3} \cdots \binom{n - n_1 - n_2 - n_3 - \cdots - n_{k - 1}}{n_k}\\
& \qquad = \frac{n!}{n_1!(n - n_1)!} \cdot \frac{(n - n_1)!}{n_2!(n - n_1 - n_2)!} \cdot \frac{(n - n_1 - n_2)!}{n_3!(n - n_1 - n_2 - n_3)!} \cdots \frac{(n - n_1 - n_2 - n_3 - \cdots - n_{k - 1})!}{n_k!(n - n_1 - n_2 - n_3 - \cdots - n_{k - 1} - n_k)!}\\
& \qquad = \frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3! \cdots n_k!(n - n_1 - n_2 - n_3 - \cdots - n_{k - 1} - n_k)!}\\
& \qquad = \frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3! \cdots n_k!0!}\\
& \qquad = \frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3! \cdots n_k!}
\end{align*}
where $n = n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + \cdots + n_k \implies n - n_1 - n_2 - n_3 - \cdots - n_k = 0$ and $0! = 1$ by definition.

If $n = n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + \cdots + n_k$, the expression
$$\binom{n}{n_1, n_2, n_3, \ldots, n_k} = \frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3! \cdots n_k!}$$
is called a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).  In the special case that $k = 2$, $n = n_1 + n_2$, so the multinomial coefficient
$$\binom{n}{n_1, n_2} = \frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!}$$
reduces to the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)
$$\binom{n}{n_1, n_2} = \frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!} = \frac{n!}{n_1!(n - n_1)!} = \binom{n}{n_1}$$